# How did someone manage to reply to this closed question?

Tags: support, bug, closed-questions

See the question [Please explain me the logic behind the given program. Also why case 2 will print 4 times [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71434526/please-explain-me-the-logic-behind-the-given-program-also-why-case-2-will-print).

From there I can currently obtain the following info:

- "asked 3 hours ago"
- "Closed 2 hours ago"
- "answered 1 hour ago"

I see no edits in the question nor in the answer.

How did someone manage to post an answer to a closed question?

Comment: So... this has been bugged since 2014 and we shouldn't care to improve the site?

Comment: ... ¯\\_(ツ\)_/¯

Comment: I find the "client side check" excuse somewhat *weak* now, i must admit. What bugs me more is the inconsistency of the "enforcement". Honestly, I would prefer it if SO just let any answers in flight be posted to the question, or none. It honestly infuriates me when someone closes a question seconds before I go to submit an answer and then I've just wasted my time (because I can't submit), and then someone else posts an answer 10 minutes later because they got around the feature.

Comment: @Lundin yes we should, but the amount of care we have does not imply action is taken. The system that is in place is designed and maintained by our overlords and not by mistake either, it is specifically designed to be like this as per the duplicate link. We don't own the site, so there is no reason to push the issue.

Comment: @Gimby I think you overestimate how much on this site that happens on purpose and how much that just happens out of historical reasons. The code base ought to have changed a whole lot since 2014 and probably a lot of the dev staff has changed too.

Comment: Wow, that answer, though...

Comment: Well yes the difficult part of the code was understanding the comma operator. Understanding a for loop can be done by reading the first chapters of a beginner-level book, so we shouldn't even need to explain it to a professional or enthusiast programmer. And then someone felt the need to post an answer to a closed question explaining how a for loop does _not_ work, while completely ignoring to explain the comma operator... If that answer had been blocked by site mechanics, it would have been a good thing.